# Java Public Void

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int deposit = 0;
    String yesno = "";
        try 
    {
        System.out.println("Do you have an account already?");
        yesno = scan1.next();
        if(yesno == "no")
            throw new Exception(" ");            
        System.out.println(yesno);
        Calculate();


    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("HAHAHA");
    }
}
public void Calculate()
{
    System.out.println("Calculate");
}
```

The `Calculate();` gives an error. How to fix this?
`C:\Users\MAC\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:48:`

I'm trying to learn new things in java because last time, I was using JavaFX but I don't know how to use the `Public void` and how to call them here in Java.

Comment: That's the file name and the line number, the error will be after it.

Comment: `Calculate` is an instance method, you're going to have to instantiate the enclosing class to use it.

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Make `calculate()` a `static` method since you are calling it from a static context.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a non-static method from a static block of code.You have to declare Calculate static or create an object of the main class and call the method to it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of your main class and then call the calculate method:

If Test is your class name:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.Calculate();
```

Other solution is to make the Calculate function static:

```
 public static void Calculate() {
 // do something
 }
```